# Massive Data Loads With Verification And Insert /Update (Cannot Upsert)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, csv, data-structures

I have a massive CSV file that I am given once a week that contains just under 5 million records.  These records need to either be added to my SQL database (MS SQL Server) or updated depending on if they exist already or not.  I thought about performing a Bulk Upsert, but the issue is that I cannnot update the records directly.  This is what the [important components of the] objects look like:

```
PatientRecord-
  int MRN; //primary key
  string first_name;
  string last_name;
  int? updated_mrn; 
  int? pat_id; //filtered unclustered unique index
```

When a record needs to be added to the system we need to first check if that MRN already exists and the rest of the data matches.  If so, the record is skipped, otherwise it gets added to a `List<PatientRecord>` of exceptions.  If the MRN is not found we need to check if that pat_id already exists.  If so, the new MRN is added the updated_mrn component of the object (and updated in the db), otherwise a new record is created.  The problem is that this takes forever.  My application uses LINQ to SQL for almost all other database transactions, but this would not be the best way to handle the weekly load/update.  I thought about performing some SQL Bulk operations to do this, but then I'd need to load all of the records from the CSV into memory.  I'm not quite sure on the the most efficient way of doing this.  My current thoughts are the following:

1. Load CSV data into memory
2. Compare object with database (Using Linq-to-sql)
3. If found-remove from structure and place in exception structure or update structure
4. Bulk Insert of non-exceptions/updates
5. Bulk Update of exception structure
6. Generate Exceptions File for manual review

My questions are as follows:
What data-structure would be the most memory efficient to hold all of this data?  Random access is not needed.
Should LINQ-to-SQL not be used to perform the verifications?  I know that it is not the best performing method of querying a database.
Am I going about this component of the project all wrong?

Any advice or suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Can you just use a `FileStream`/`StreamReader` and read record by record?  It sounds like you only need to have 1 record in memory at any time.

Comment: Adding one record at a time to the database would take an extremely long time though.

Comment: To be fair, doing this in C# at all will be considerably longer than a TSQL solution (bulk insert into staging table, process records set-based, etc.).  You can fire the process with C# if it's really needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing answers are good, but I'll add one major point: You can keep lots of logic in the application without problems, if you perform selects and DML in **big batches**. Always send **few, big queries** to the database. That saves in the following places: roundtrip times, network bandwidth, per-transaction costs, per-batch costs and per-statement costs. It also gives the optimizer the opportunity to perform bulk operations. Sorting 1M rows is much faster than sorting 1000x1000 rows. In aggregate these make up for orders of magnitude speedup.

SQL Server does not have bulk update or merge, but you can bulk insert into a staging table and then execute one merge/update for everything at once.

The point is: you can do whatever you want as long as you use few and bulky operations. You don't need to run everything in T-SQL.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating by what you mean by "use few and bulky operations?"   I believe that you are saying that I should use a few, but really 'expensive' operations to pull large datasets to perform my validations, and then push it all back at once.  I just wanted to make sure I understood correctly.

Comment: You got it. A negative example would be that you execute 1m queries to pull one row each. Better would be to pull all 1m at once and buffer them in memory (potentially stuffing them into a hash table). The same applies to writes.; This is the primary rule you have to obey to get great performance for high-throughput ETL.

Comment: Thanks a lot this did the trick!  Basically I did a bulk load, verified data in a staging table.  Deleted a batch of bad records (and placed in a holding structure) and then performed a merge via StoredProc.  Fast, Efficient, and fulfilled all my needs without SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with SSIS and TSQL the following should be fairly straight forward and easy to maintain. 
First, create an ssis package to load the raw data into a sql server table. If MRN is known to be unique per file, you can index this new "RAW" table accordingly.

Second, create a stored procedure to [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) the RAW data to your production tables.  Merge will perform inserts, updates or deletes in a single operation.

Finally, you can wrap it all up in a SQL Server Agent job.

I hope this helps...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SSIS, but I'll take a look at what it can do for this project.  The only catch is that although the MRN is supposed to be unique in practice there are some dupes, which is why I was performing additional verification.  On the last load it found ~10,000 exceptions where a mrn was duplicated or re-used.  This why I need to clean the data beforehand. (0.2% bad data rate)

Comment: It wouldn't let me edit my last comment, but that load took 8 hours to run, hence why I want to redesign the data-load component of the application.

Comment: SSIS is created for this exact purpose.  You can chain a workflow of data sources and destinations together.  This is fairly standard ETL process in the database world, and there should be a wealth of information at hand to do this.

Comment: @tommy_o Thanks for the info.  I'm actually researching SSIS now.  My TSQL skills aren't what they used to be, but I should be able to something together.  I'm not a big database guy so it usually isn't my first go-to.

Comment: Doh! I only have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express at my disposal!  Looks like I need standard or higher.

Comment: If you don't want to use SSIS and you only need to move the data into SQL Server, then use it, you could alternatively do this: 1.) bulk load the data (via command-line bcp.exe or Bulk Insert) into a staging table; 2.) build appropriate indexing on your staging table; 3.) merge the staging table with the real table using TSQL `MERGE`.  Then you don't need SSIS at all :)

Comment: BCP.EXE is the fastest way to load data into SQL Server.  `Bulk Insert` is the second.  Both can be used in a similar manner to load into a staging table before processing the data.

Answer (score 1):

I would use SqlBulkCopy in C#

1 / Load CSV data into **staging table** using SqlBulkCopy

2/ Compare **staging table** with database (Using Linq-to-sql or any other SQL code)

3/ If found-remove from structure and place in exception structure or update structure

4/ Sql Bulk copy Bulk Insert of non-exceptions/updates

You should not use Linq-2-Sql for your inserts because it will do them one-by-one (There is no batch insert in L2S)